# How to install a node to get a balance of addresses?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, ethereumjs, openethereum

We need to install the ETH client in order to receive balances of different addresses using GetBalance (https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth.html#getbalance).
Please tell me, do we need to download a full node or a pruned one? How long will the sync process take and what can be the difficulties?

And which client to use?

Comment: You do not need to install a node. There are both free and commercial Ethereum JSON-RPC service providers: https://ethereumnodes.com/

Comment: However if you choose to install a node it is simple as well: https://twitter.com/moo9000/status/1370323189486784513

Answer (score 0):

> Please tell me, do we need to download a full node or a pruned one?

Both light or full node will work if you want to get balance. However, note that if using a light node, the light node will require to connect to another full node to obtain this information, so queries will be slower and will fail if your node fails to connect to a full node.

> How long will the sync process take and what can be the difficulties?

This depends on your configuration and your network. We cannot answer.

> And which client to use?

As you do not provide any parameter for us to work with, there is no objective possible answer to this question.